# Laravel Eloquent Repository query buildup

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, repository-pattern

I have a table `Schedule` that has the following columns: `id, day, month, year`. Directly using `Eloquent`, I have defined query functions for `day`, `month`, and `year`. I can then get the schedule using:

```
return Schedule::day($day)
                 ->month($month)
                 ->year($year)
                 ->get();
```

I sometimes also want to get all the days, or months, or years:

```
return Schedule::day($day)
                 ->get()
```

I wanted to create a repository, and implemented the following interface:

**ScheduleRepositoryInterface**

```
<?php 
namespace CLG\Storage\Schedule;

interface ScheduleRepositoryInterface
{
    public function day($day);
    public function month($month);
    public function year($year);
    public function get();  
}
```

Now I don't know how to implement it so that I can still build the query the same way? I don't want to create functions such as `getDay($day)` or `getDayAndMonth($day, $month)` and ... .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `interface` should be:

```
interface ScheduleRepositoryInterface
{
    public function day($day = null);
    public function month($month = null);
    public function year($year = null);
}
```

Your `Concrete Class` implementation could be something like this:

```
public function scopeDay($query, $day = null)
{
    return is_null($day) ? $query : $query->whereDay($day);
}
```

You may use following code ('select') to select only `day` column:

```
return is_null($day) ? $query->select('day') : $query->whereDay($day)->select('day');
```

Same way, you may declare other functions for `month` and `year`.